# Unable to convert time to STRFTIME in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a database program where the user can send a custom log request from a client to the program. The timestamp is converted to EPOCH time and transferred to the program, where protobufs handle the conversion to time.

The time is received and converted into this format: `2022-6-2 3:6:8`. Parsing this timestamp into the database to retrieve a time period does not work because it expects the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I have tried to use the `STRFTIME` format option in sqlite3 however testing it on my database returns no results.

The query I am testing is:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN DATETIME(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2022-06-02 01:3:0')) AND DATETIME(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2022-06-02 01:4:0'));
```

Comment: SQLite's datetime functions work only with the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: @forpas yeah I also tried `SELECT * FROM database WHERE DATE_TIME BETWEEN STRFTIME('%YYYY-%mm-%dd %HH:%MM:%SS', '2022-06-02 01:16:0') AND STRFTIME('%YYYY-%mm-%dd %HH:%MM:%SS','2022-06-02 01:17:0');
` which returned the same

Comment: This was annoying me so I have decided to change the client program as well. The person who originally wrote this was sending d,m,y h,m,s individually for from and to time. so 6x2 of the same epoch lol... I am going to just send epoch time and process that with `STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(<epoch>,'unixepoch'))`

Comment: `datetime(<epoch>,'unixepoch')` will do. No need for strftime().